# Additional firebase database field being added automatically?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a book class as

```
public class Books {

    public String bookName;
    public String author;
    public String copies;

    public Books() {
        // Default constructor required for calls to DataSnapshot.getValue(User.class)
    }

    public Books(String name, String author, String copies) {
        this.bookName = name;
        this.author = author;
        this.copies = copies;
    }

    public String getBookName() {
        return bookName;
    }

    public String getAuthorName() {
        return author;
    }


    public String getCopies() {
        return copies;
    }

}
```

And i'm adding to firebase realtime cloud database as

```
mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance("https://cmpe-2b339.firebaseio.com").getReference();

Books book = new Books(bookName,author,copies);
                    mDatabase.push().setValue(book);
```

However in firebase concole, its coming as

```
{
  "-KzAt3eHDBtD7gFvLIbn" : {
    "author" : "J",
    "authorName" : "J",
    "bookName" : "Hi",
    "copies" : "5"
  }
}
```

There is added author field, which i dont understand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a public variable named "author" and a public getter named "getAuthorName". Firebase reflection is using both to create the data in the database. Fix: make your variables private and keep the getters, then add the setters.

Comment: What does this mean. It fixed the issue ?

Comment: Reflection is a Java property where you can access another class without knowing the name of the methods or variables. Firebase use reflection to examine the calss is being uploaded. That is why you are supposed to use standar POJO java classes for this.The other answer is pointing in the same direction.

Answer (score 1):

Replace your class with this

```
public class Books {
private String bookName;
private String author;
private String copies;

public Books () {

}

public Books(String bookName, String author, String copies) {
    this.bookName = bookName;
    this.author = author;
    this.copies = copies;
}

public String getBookName() {
    return bookName;
}

public void setBookName(String bookName) {
    this.bookName = bookName;
}

public String getAuthor() {
    return author;
}

public void setAuthor(String author) {
    this.author = author;
}

public String getCopies() {
    return copies;
}

public void setCopies(String copies) {
    this.copies = copies;
}
}
```